# how to filter xsltlistviewwebpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

how i could filter programmatically the xsltlistviewwebpart:

```
   //this is the web part
    <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="WebPartZone1"    
    Title="loc:Main"><ZoneTemplate>
      <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" ...>

        <ParameterBindings>
      ...

       </ParameterBindings>
     <DataFields>
    </DataFields>
   <XmlDefinition>
   <View ...><Query><Where>...</Where></Query><ViewFields>...</ViewFields><RowLimit   
    Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit><JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink><XslLink 
    Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink><Toolbar Type="Standard"/></View>  
   </XmlDefinition>

   </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>

  </ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>


      SPWebPartManager wpm = SPWebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager(this.Page) 
        as  SPWebPartManager;

     SPList list = web.Lists["listname"];

      foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart current in wpm.WebParts)
      {
          if (current is XsltListViewWebPart)
          {
                XsltListViewWebPart XsltListViewWebPart1 = current as 
                XsltListViewWebPart;

               StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
     xml.Append("<View Name='" + 

    list.DefaultView.ID.ToString("B").ToString().ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
    + "' TabularView='FALSE' MobileView='TRUE' Type='HTML'  Hidden='TRUE' 
     DisplayName=''  Level='1' BaseViewID='1' ContentTypeID='0x' ImageUrl='/_layouts
    /images/generic.png'>");   Url='" + Request.Url.ToString() + "' 
   xml.Append("<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='LinkFilename'/><Value Type='Text'> " 
   + name + " </Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID'/></OrderBy></Query>");
   xml.Append("<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='LinkFilename'/><FieldRef   
    Name='Auteur'/></ViewFields>");
   xml.Append("<RowLimit Paged='TRUE'>20</RowLimit>");
   xml.Append("</View>");



    XsltListViewWebPart1.XmlDefinition = xml.ToString();
        wpm.SaveChanges(XsltListViewWebPart1.StorageKey);
           web.Update();

           }
     }
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. The XSLTListViewWebpart needs a dataconnection that contains a CAML query. You can add filters to that CAML query? But that is not what you want?

Comment: i made sth like this: for XmlDefinition but does not work

Comment: Can you explain what exactly the requirements are? I mean, the XSLTListViewWebpart has all the filter capabilities you should need.

Comment: the requirement is to filter this web part show only some items : precisely the user might filter by items name bias with textbox above the web part grid.

Comment: you could see Query tag in xml definition

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer to your question, but I just want to get this out of the way to make sure you're not making things too difficult for yourself.

XSLTListViewWebparts already have very extensive filtering capabilities which you can very easily talk to by clicking on the sort button on top of each column.

If you want to talk to it directly, you can use the querystring. Just use the following format:

```
/site/Lists/mylist/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=MYCOLUMN1&FilterValue1=MYVALUE1&FilterField2=MYCOLUMN2&FilterValue2=MYVALUE2
```

This is for a list/library view, but this querystring can be used anywhere.

You can also connect it by using any kind of Filter webpart and connect both webparts to each other. (These are available in the enterprise edition of SharePoint, to enable them, enable the enterprise feature). Choice Filter, Business Data Catalog Filter, SharePoint List Filter, etc.

Comment: Don't forget to mark my post as answer if it works for you and or upvote if it's usefull. Thanks